# send ios push notifications to a python, raspberry pi 3 with bluetooth

Tags: python, ios, iphone, bluetooth, apple-push-notifications

I wanna build a device, which can connect to my phone (iPhone) via Bluetooth and receives the notifications (Text-Message, missed or incoming phone call or game notifications and so on)

I found different solutions how to send notifications to my phone but none otherwise around. I looked at APNs and ANCS and thought that would be the solution but it wasn't or I couldn't figure it out how to do it.

The program should be able to react depending on which notification came in. Also in delay. For example that I can code that the program gives me all the emails from the last half hour or so.

My device is a raspberry 3 with Bluetooth 4.1.

Is it possible to do what I would like to, or not?

Thanks for your answer